# Saving Converted Int in Const Char* Array Fails on Windows

Tags: c++, arrays, int, type-conversion

I want to access a "number" in a const char* array, subtract a number from another const char* array and then save the result back in the first const char* array.
I have this code working just fine on Linux, but in Windows (VS 2015 RC) it just doesn't work.

```
int i = atoi(CharArr1[0][6]); //if printed shows 100
i -= atoi(CharArr2[0][2]); //if printed shows 93 (100-7)
CharArr1[0][6] = std::to_string(i).c_str(); //if I print the conversion, it shows 93 | if I print CharArr1[0][6] it shows nothing
```

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Does this help? `CharArr1[0][6] = std::to_string(i).c_str()[0];`

Comment: @Cameron That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CharArr1[0][6] = std::to_string(i).c_str();
```

That lines stores a pointer at `CharArr1[0][6]` that is invalid after the line since it is a pointer to the data held by a temporary `std::string` object.

If you want to use it a little bit longer, create an object first.

```
std::string temp = std::to_string(i);
CharArr1[0][6] = temp.c_str();
```

Then, `CharArr1[0][6]` will hold a pointer that is valid as long as `temp` is in scope.

Answer (score 0):

`std::to_string(i)` returns a string object. You then ask for the internal storage pointer (via `c_str()`) of that object. The object is then destroyed immediately after, since its lifetime expires, leaving the pointer pointing to a freed buffer. Subsequent code causes the data at that address to change.

This only worked by coincidence before! You need to extend the lifetime of the string object (e.g. by keeping it on the stack) until you no longer need it.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that information. I want to be honest, I am somewhat new to programming (not a total newb though) and just copied that from somewhere, thinking c_str() would convert from string to char ; well, I guess I should do more research on commands I want to use and don't know ^^ I was able to fix my problem with itoa